# Understanding Antisymmetry from a table

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I understood how to see if a relation $R$ is antisymmetric, but how can I understand it from these tables?
For example:

With $X = \{\,a, b\,\}$

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
  & a & b \\\hline
a & 1 & 1 \\\hline
b & 0 & 1 \\\hline
\end{array}$$

$R$ IS antisymmetric.

With $X = \{\,a, b, c\,\}$

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
  & a & b & c \\\hline
a & 1 & 0 & 1 \\\hline
b & 1 & 0 & 0 \\\hline
c & 1 & 0 & 1 \\\hline
\end{array}$$

$R$ is NOT antisymmetric.

Why? What do I have to look at to understand the process?

Comment: Welcome to math.sx! You may read [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) about mathematics formatting.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting, I didn't know I could have made tables that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $R_{i,j}$ is the entry in row $i$, column $j$ of the table of relation $R$, the table of an antisymmetric relation has no occurrences of $R_{i,j} = R_{j,i} = 1$ whenever $i \neq j$.   It's nothing but the definition of antisymmetry.

In your second example, $R_{1,3} = R_{3,1} = 1$, which says that $a$ is related to $c$ and vice versa; yet $a$ is distinct from $c$.  Hence $R$ is not antisymmetric.

Comment: Thank you very much! You explained very well and I got it!